# Three JS - JsonLoader import of blender object and materials

Tags: json, three.js, blender

I succeed to load my obj file with the JSON loader of three JS however I can't succeed to have the materials too. I have two errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined @ three.min.js:455h....
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transparent' of undefined
```

Here is the code I use to load the object on the scene:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("obj/littlebig.json", function(geometry, mat) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(mat);
        var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        object.scale.set(100, 100, 100);
        scene.add(object);
    }
);
```

Here is the export from blender: http://pastebin.com/Uae3qC1w. (I voluntarily removed some uvs, vertex and normals).

And here is the screenshot of the export I made from blender:

[image]

Here is the a part of the value of the mat variable, if you need the rest I will upload it:

[image]

Do you see what is wrong?

Edit : I tried many things and it seems that my export was bad, because with another model I succeed to load the materials, so if you see what options I miss...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Take a look at the example i created .
Its modular , and allows you to load materials and animations easily.

https://github.com/master-atul/blender3js

I hope it helps :)